# Do we have to say technically correctly "they changed the flat inner tube for a new inner tube" or just "they changed the flat for a new tire"?

Tags: phrase-usage

[image]

[image]

Look at the 2 above pictures, we can distinguish an inner tube, a tire and a wheel.

> [inner tube](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/inner-tube) (noun): ​a rubber tube filled with air inside a tyre
>
> [a tyre](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tyre?q=tyre) (noun): a thick rubber ring that fits around the edge of a
> wheel of a car, bicycle, etc.
>
> a [wheel](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wheel_1?q=wheel) (noun):  one of the round objects under a car, bicycle, bus,
> etc. that turns when it moves

However,

> [a spare tyre](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spare-tyre?q=spare%20tire): an extra wheel for a car

So, **a spare tyre** is a wheel.

**Situation 1:**

Suppose your car has a spare tyre. When your car has a puncture or a flat tire, you change the whole wheel with its tyre and its flat inner tube for the spare tyre.

In this situation, it is not technically correct to say "**I changed the flat tyre for the spare tyre**" because you changed the tyre and the flat inner tube for a whole wheel. **How is that possible?**

Do we have to say technically correctly "**I changed the wheel with flat tyre for the spare tyre**"?

**Situation 2:**

Suppose your car doesn't have a spare tyre. When your car has a puncture or a flat tire, you called a car mechanic and the man will change only "**the inner tube**" of the flat tire, not the whole wheel or even the tire.

In this situation, it is not technically correct to say "**the mechanic changed my flat tyre for a new tyre**".

Do we have to say "**the mechanic changed my flat inner tube for a new inner tube**"?

However in Vietnamese, we say "**the mechanic changed my flat tyre for a new tyre**" even though he just changed **the flat inner tube** for **a new inner tube**. Maybe the same thing is in English.

**What do we say in both situations?**

Comment: The vast majority of car tyres have not had inner-tubes since the 1920s!

Comment: Oxford Learner's is misleading (in fact, incorrect) here. A spare **tyre** is just a **tyre** (or 'tire' if you prefer). What most cars carry in case of puncture on the road is a spare **wheel**.

Comment: Bicycles and motorcycles may often use tyres with inner tubes.

Comment: No, we don't go into technical detail because everyone knows that when you get a flat tyre on your car you 'change the wheel' and then you go to the garage to 'get a new tyre'.

Comment: The tyre & tube pictured are for a motorcycle, not a car.

Comment: A tire (or tyre in BrE) is  not a wheel, folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a car gets a flat, even though we almost always change the whole wheel, we say we're "changing the tire" (I use the Canadian spelling). It's not technically correct, but it's what we say. If a mechanic comes, he'll bring a spare wheel with him because car tires don't have inner tubes, but if he did change only the tube, we would still say he "changed the tire".

Even with bicycles which have inner tubes, it's common to hear people say they "*need a new tire*" when they just need a new inner tube. Serious cyclists are more precise, and will say they're replacing the tube.

Also, it's worth noting that with flat tires, we don't say "*change the tire **for a new tire***". English doesn't like repetition, so we simply say, "*change the tire*". It's understood that you change it for a new one. Same goes with tubes or any other part. The only time you'd specify what you changed it for is if there's something about it you want to specify, like, "*I changed my front tire for a slicker one*".

Comment: The mechanic brings a spare tire, not a wheel.

Comment: @Lambie How does the mechanic mount the tire on the rim?

Comment: Not by bringing a wheel. He brings a tire. In the language, we just don't say wheel here.

Comment: @Lambie Are you saying the mechanic literally brings only a tire, or that the mechanic actually brings a wheel, but my wording is in correct and I should call the wheel a "spare tire"?

Comment: Yes, a road assistance guy (usually guys) might change your tire with the spare you have in the trunk (boot) or bring a new one. In the trade, they don't bring a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Car tyres do not have inner tubes (there may be some exceptions but none that I've heard of in 30 years of driving), so the short answer would be **no**. If you get a puncture we either get the tyre repaired or changed.

Bicycles on the other hand still have inner tubes, so in the case of a puncture on a bike we would probably say specifically what was changed. Inner tubes are normally changed or repaired due to punctures or perished material; tyres normally due to loss of tread.

When any kind of tyre is flat, we tend to say "I got a flat tyre" (or just "I got a flat", though this is chiefly US English). At that point, we may not know the reason it is flat so there's no point assuming it is the inner tube.

Also worth noting is that most cars carry a spare wheel in the back for emergencies. It is my observation that while most people refer to this as a 'spare wheel', some call it a 'spare tyre'.

Comment: So for a bike or motorbike, we have to say "**I changed the flat inner tube for a new one**"?

Comment: @Tom Well, to be picky, I wouldn't change an inner tube just because it was *flat* - I'd pump it up. But if the reason it keeps going flat is because it has a puncture, yes I'd change it. We say "I got a flat tyre", or sometimes just "I got a flat" (the latter is chiefly US English).

Comment: for a a bike or motorbike, is it still ok to say "**my bike had a flat so I changed the flat for a new tyre**"?

Comment: @tom yes, if it is the tyre that you changed. Also, I don't know anything about motorbike tyres. I drive cars and bicycles.

Comment: "At that point, we may not know the reason it is flat so there's no point assuming it is the inner tube." It always is. But it's unclear what exactly is wrong with the inner tube.